# How do you install a package to a sandbox while logged in via "Grant Login Access"?

Tags: sandbox, grant-login-access, package-install

A customer wants me to install a package for them. They have granted me login access via the "Grant Login Access" option. I log in to my SFDC account with the LMA (License Management App), go to Subscribers, pick their org, and login as them.

Now, the tricky part comes when I try to access the installation URL. Sometimes it wants to install it to MY org (the one I used to get tot heir sandbox). Sometimes it asks me to log in - I don't have the login credentials of the sandbox, I bypassed that with "Grant Login Access". Sometimes (very rarely) it just seems to work.

Is there a trick to this or do I just need to have the user install it themselves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the install URL to their instance instead of login or test, and paste it into your address bar after logging in.

Comment: Ugh, yes, as soon as I saw this I knew that's what it was. The install URL will usually be login.salesforce.com - you just change the login part to whatever their subdomain is. I know that's what you said, just clarifying for anyone else that stumbles across this.